# How do I show an external JS function (returns array) into a html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am developing a mobile application. I need to show an array in a list on my html. I have a function in an external `.js` file which returns an array with JSON data retrieved.

This is my function in javascript:

```js
function getnames() {
  var url = api + "/name";
  $.getJSON(url).done(function (answer) {
    if (!answer.length) {
      console.warn("Empty list");
    }
    api.name = response;
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      $('#names').html(api.name[i].name);
    }

  }).fail(function (data, status, error) {
    console.error("Something went wrong");
  });
}
```

This is the html list I want them to be displayed in:

```html
<div>
  <div class="widget-container">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a>
        <h4 id="names">
          <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
              getnames();
            };
          </script>
        </h4>
      </a>
      this is repeated 4 times.I have 4 headings meaning i need for 4 names            which is as much the array returns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The list i would like to display them in is a menu from a panel. The code I have only shows me the last name for some reason.

Comment: Don't use `window.onload`... it is rarely necessary, and jQuery `.ready` is nicer/better anyway.

Comment: Why do you use the `a` tag? And please realise that you should never repeat something that will result in duplicate `id` attribute values -- which is not allowed in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate a `h4` tag for each of the array elements.

Some issues in your code:

- There is no use in putting your `script` tag at the place where you want to inject data. Just place it just before the closing `</body>` tag or else in the `<head>` tag;
- Don't use `window.load`. There are specific cases where it could be useful, but not in your case. Instead use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, or, as you use jQuery, the equivalent [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) method;
- You name the JSON response argument `answer`, but then start referring to `response`: obviously you should stick to the same variable name;
- You assign multiple times HTML to the same element `#names`, so that you overwrite the previous value and are left with the last value only;
- You use the `html` method for an argument that is pure text. This is not advised, as you can get problems with text that contains `<` or `&` characters, as they have a special meaning in HTML. Instead you should use `.text()`;
- You use the `api` variable in strange ways. First it seems to be a string (in `url = api + "/name"`), and then later you assign to its `name` property. Although this can work, it makes your code obscure. If it really is an object, then the first statement will be equal to `url = api.toString() + "/name"`;
- The code never adds another `h4` element, which seems to be what you want. For that to happen you could generate the necessary `h4` elements dynamically.

Here is the code adapted accordingly, which makes use of a fake JSON provider:

```js
var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

function getnames() {
  var url = api + "/posts"; // change to "/name"
  $.getJSON(url).done(function (response) {
    if (!response.length) {
      console.warn("Empty list");
    }
    $.map(response, function(item) {
      $('.list-group').append($('<h4>').text(item.title)); // change to item.name
    });
  }).fail(function (data, status, error) {
    console.error("Something went wrong");
  });
}

$(function() {
    getnames();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="widget-container">
    <div class="list-group">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#names').html(api.name[i].name); // You are overwriting with each loop
```

Try:

```
$('#names').append(api.name[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to avoid when working with HTML content is repeated updates: each time you update the DOM, the browser checks if it needs to update the display, and potentially kicks off a load of recalculations, repaints and other expensive processes. It's much better, if you can, to build up the content you want to update, and then insert it into the DOM in one step, like this:

```
function getnames() {
  var url = api + "/name";
  $.getJSON(url).done(function (answer) {
    if (!answer.length) {
      console.warn("Empty list");
    }

    // jQuery map gives you a new array of the returned values: 
    names = $.map(answer, function(e){
      return e.name;
    });

    // Join turns the array into a string, separated with ', '
    $('#names').html(names.join(', '));

  }).fail(function (data, status, error) {
    console.error("Something went wrong");
  });
}
```

This code takes the `answer` from the getJSON call, and transforms it into an array of just the name properties. Join then turns it into a comma separated string, which is passed the the `html` method on `#names`.

I hope that's clear enough - let me know if it makes sense!